# Is there a known fast algorithm to find the $k^\text{th}$ root modulo a prime?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algorithms

I was trying to write an algorithm, but I got stuck at a point.
Is there a known computationally fast algorithm to find kth root of an integer modulo a prime n, with k being odd and coprime to n.
I know that a method to find square and cube root exist but, do not know if we can find any general kth root.
Can anyone please help.

Comment: See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1664946/solving-xe-c-in-mathbbf-p) for how to solve a similar problem: finding an $e$'th root (where $e\in\mathbb Z$, $e\ge 1$ and $\gcd(e,p-1)=1$) of $c\in\mathbb Z$ mod a prime $p$. The difference in this case is that $e$ has to be coprime to $p-1$ (therefore also odd if $p$ is odd) instead of $p$.

Comment: if the condition of gcd(e, p-1)=1 is not met, is there any way to solve the equation?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm

Comment: If the gcd is not $1$. there may not be a solution.

Comment: it's something like this, i have integer m <= n-1 and I do $m^a$ for some a, with gcd(a, n-1) not equal to 1. Can i retrieve m back? all operations are modulo n.